# On the (not) locally compactness of the rationals.

Tags: general-topology

I recently started reading topology.I thought of a proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ with the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}$ is not locally compact, but I m not sure if it is correct. I'd appreciate if someone could check it. Here it goes: let $K$ be a compact neighbourhood of $0$. K itself, with the induced topology should be compact( I think), so any infinite sequence of points in $K$ should have a limit point. But now, since $K$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ it should contain some $(a,b)\cap{\mathbb{Q}}$, for some $ab<0$, where I can find some irrational $c\in{(a,b)}$ and a rational sequence converging to it, therefore $c$ being it's only limit point, contradicting the compactness of $K$. Is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a correct argument: $(a,b) \subseteq K$ and pick $p$ irrational in $(a,b)$ and $q_n$ a rational sequence in $(a,b)$ converging to $p$ in the reals (!). Then $\{c_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ has only one limit point (i.e. $p$) in the reals, so has *no* limit point in $\Bbb Q$, and lies in $K$, which is a contradiction.

Note that the argument can be held for any $D$ in a metric space that is dense and whose complement is also dense in the space.